# Spline interpolation: cubic vs. piecewise Hermite with C2 continuity

Tags: math, interpolation, spline

I didn't get much of a bite in math.stackexchange.com, so I'll try here...

Recently, I've been looking to find the interpolating cubic spline of some data that I have. I think I have a pretty good understanding of how it works: take x,y data, plug into a tridiagonal matrix, solve for the 2nd derivative of y(i), and calculate coefficients from the 2nd derivative.

However, I ran across an article in Game Programming Gems 5 which uses a cubic *Hermite* spline with *C2* continuity. This article uses a tridiagonal matrix to solve the linear equations, but it's actually solving for the 1st derivative instead of the second. After some more investigation, I noticed that Scilab also uses a Hermite spline with C2 continuity. Their splin() function returns the slopes of the input data.

Is there any advantage to using a C2 Hermite spline over a plain old cubic spline when it comes to interpolating data? If both have C2 continuity, I don't quite understand why you would use one over the other.

Thanks!

Comment: "I didn't get much of a bite in math.stackexchange.com, so I'll try here..."... by the same logic, you should also post at cooking.stackexchange.com I'm sure they'll provide the answer.

Comment: Also, its only been 5 hours since you posted [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62360/natural-cubic-splines-vs-piecewise-hermite-splines). Patience, Grasshopper.

Comment: @PengOne: the snark isn't necessary. If you don't know the answer, then please move on.

Comment: Perhaps the sarcasm isn't necessary, but the point I'm making is. Do not repost on multiple sites, especially when your question is off topic here. Wait. Add a bounty. Don't spam us.

Comment: There are plenty of math questions on stackoverflow.com. It's hardly spamming or off-topic. Also, math.stackexchange.com seemed like a dead community.

Comment: I don't know if this question is entirely out of place here -- as pointed out, these are techniques used in different programming libraries, etc. (Just because *you* don't use splines doesn't mean *other programmers* don't.) Also, while being posted relatively soon after the question on math.stackexchange.com, it has been rewritten and asks different questions so.... +1 to counteract the -1.

Comment: It's not a programming question, lhumongous. It doesn't belong here. Kindly don't clutter things up when you should know better.

Comment: It was rewritten since I thought that original was long-winded. I thought that I would just get to the meat of my question.

Comment: +1 from me also for an interesting computational question.

Comment: Voted to re-open because, as per the FAQ, this is a *practical, answerable* question that generally covers a *specific programming problem* and *software algorithm* -- how best to perform numerical interpolation.

Comment: Also voted to reopen. I'd expect the kinds of answers you'd get here may be quite different to those from math.stackexchange.com ... potentially more relevant to software development.